# Android service that never die

Tags: android, service, sms

I need to create a service that monitor sms received and sent.

The only work of the process will be listen to the sms and save them in the database

But, this service can't die, I can't stop to listen.

After some research, I found that I can start a service with startForeground.

Documentation of startForeground:

> A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but in practice this should not be a concern.)

Before I start to program the service, I thought in asking for a better option, if have one.

So, somebody knows a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read up on [Android fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html). You don't need a constantly running service. Just register a broadcast receiver for the appropriate intent and send an intent to your service from there (Android will automatically start it as necessary).